# Clearing fields using the same UIAlertVIew with different methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a methods that clears all my `UITextFields` in the `UIViewController`.
I have a lot of methods that trigger that function before taking place. I want to ask the user using an `UIAlertView` if it's ok to clear fields before the action is taking place.
I'm aware of `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` but don't really want to use it because my switch will look like this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(alertView.tag == 2000)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
          // do stuff
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
    if(alertView.tag == 3000)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
          // do stuff
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
etc..
```

I'm searching for an elegant way to trigger the same `UIAlertView` before every function that needs to clear the screen before it's triggered.

Thanks

Comment: You can use if-else on the basis of title:if ( [alert.title isEqualToString:@"Error"]) {  // do things here };

Answer (score -2):

```
@interface 

//Keep a global references or repeated use...
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIAlertView *myAlertView;

@end



@implementation

-(void)alertViewCallingMethod
{
    //Generate the alertView on the same handle for repeated use.
     myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWith..... ];
     myAlertView.delegate = self;
     [myAlertView show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(alertView == myAlertView)
    {
        //do you stuff...
    }
}

@end
```

The question asker says in the end

> I'm searching for an elegant way to trigger the same UIAlertView before every function that needs to clear the screen before it's triggered.

Depending upon the above requirement, my answer to the question is most appropriate. I gave you answer that can USE THE SAME HANDLE for repeated use of alertView objects and which turn removes all the un-necessary checks of tagging separate UIAlertView and write a check code for each in the delegate.

Comment: If you vote down my answer then at least write the reason behind it. My answer is proper enough for a programmer to understand. Any newbies here kindly don't vote down unnecessarily.

Comment: You are getting down voted because your answer got nothing to do with the question plus you have an example of something that I wrote I don't want to do. Try to read the question again, programmer.

Comment: Downvoters, write your own answers here before downvoting mine.